# Internet access through another computer

Tags: networking, internet, ip

I have two PCs with Ubuntu 14.04 on both of them and I want to have internet access for the second one through the first one. I tried to put first one's ip addresss as default gateway for second one and I turned on ip_forwarding but it doesn't seem to work.
Is there any usable guides that I can use to do this?

**Edit**
Both computers have wired connection and both have ip address behind a NAT but they can ping each other since they are both in the same subnet.
And they have only 1 NIC 
They both have internet access but I want packets from one computer goes through the other one.

Comment: @user68186 I edited my question

Comment: @EricCarvalho I saw that post before but it says the sharing PC must have two NICs and I'm wondering if it's possible to do it with one NIC

Comment: @user68186 Yes, they both have internet access on their own. But I want all the packets from one computer go through the other one

Comment: @user68186 I'm doing some measurements for my research. And no I don't want http proxy because I'm testing some TCP and UDP based protocols and http is only TCP based.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 1):

You should enable *routing* or in Linux terms `ip_forwarding` on the gateway machine first by using this command:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

then by setting the client's gateway to the gateway machine, it should work. Although if your gateway machine has public IP address and isn't behind a NAT (e.g. a broadband Router), you should configure NAT on it as well by using the following command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o externaleth -j SNAT --to externalip
```

note: replace the IP address with yours.